# Get list folder in listitem of sharepoint in vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint

I am currently working on sharepoint and try to get list folder in list item.
Structure of sharePoint is

```
 - Calendar 
 - Documents 
   + Folder A
     + Folder A1
     + Folder A2
     + Folder A3
   + Folder B
   + Folder C
 - Tasks
```

In vb.net, by use below code, I can get Folder A, B, C. But I don't know how to get list of items in folder A (Folder A1, A2, A3)

```
    Dim listService As New listsWS.Lists()
    listService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    listService.Url = "https://sites.inside-share.bosch.com/sites/091650/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
    Dim xmlDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()


    Dim nodeListItems As System.Xml.XmlNode = listService.GetListItems("Documents", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using SharePoint web services directly (asmx files) try using client library Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and CSOM code (Client SharePoint Object Model) if you are connecting remotely or use SSOM (Microsoft.SharePoint.dll) when you try to connect from SharePoint server.

Then you can use Objects (in SSOM) like SPWeb SPList SPQuery SPFolder to get items in folder. 
e.g. web.Lists["Documents"].RootFolder.SubFolders["A"].SubFolders["A1"].Files.

Learn what is SharePoint CAML to know more how to query SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your new solution, Let me try with your way :)